# Scalar multiplication of an expression containing equality

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization

Suppose:

```
expr=(a x + a y==0);
expr/a
(*Out:=(a x + a y==0)/a*)
```

I want `a` eliminated to obtain `expr=(x+y==0)`. None of `Expand, Simplify, FullSimplify` work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Thread[]`:

```
expr = a x + a y == 0;
Thread[expr/a, Equal] // Simplify
   x + y == 0
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. I also found another way: `Assuming[a != 0, Simplify[expr]]`